# Rails 3 check if attribute changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Need to check if a block of attributes has changed before update in Rails 3.

street1, street2, city, state, zipcode

I know I could use something like

```
if @user.street1 != params[:user][:street1]
  then do something....
end
```

But that piece of code will be REALLY long.  Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 297, accepted):

Check out [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) (available on all models by default). The documentation is really good, but it lets you do things such as:

```
@user.street1_changed? # => true/false
```

Comment: This doesn't help if you're trying to see whether an attribute was changed in a form (which seems to be what the OP is doing).

Comment: Sure it does. If you assign the values using the params hash, these have come from the form.

Comment: what if I would want to do something like this: 

model.collection.changed_size_by? or something like

Comment: @MauroDias you'd have to write your own logic to track collection properties like that.

Answer (score 59):

**This is how I solved the problem of checking for changes in multiple attributes.**

```
attrs = ["street1", "street2", "city", "state", "zipcode"]

if (@user.changed & attrs).any?
  then do something....
end
```

The [`changed`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed) method returns an array of the attributes changed for that object.

Both `@user.changed` and `attrs` are arrays so I can get the intersection (see [`ary & other ary`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-26) method). The result of the intersection is an array. By calling `any?` on the array, I get true if there is at least one intersection.

Also very useful, the [`changed_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed_attributes) method returns a hash of the attributes with their original values and the [`changes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changes) returns a hash of the attributes with their original and new values (in an array).

You can check APIDock for which versions supported these methods.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty

Comment: This is a nice way of doing it.  Historically I've done `if attrs.any?{|attr| @user.send("#{attr}_changed?")}` When I want to check if one of several different attributes have changed -- Of course, I only do this with attrs that I've defined myself, because I don't like throwing user params into a `send` method. ;)

Comment: `previously_changed` adaptation, usually in after_commit:
`if (@user.previous_changes.keys & attrs).any?`

Answer (score 19):

**For rails 5.1+ callbacks**

As of Ruby on Rails 5.1, the `attribute_changed?` and `attribute_was` ActiveRecord methods will be deprecated

Use `saved_change_to_attribute?` instead of `attribute_changed?`

```
@user.saved_change_to_street1? # => true/false
```

More examples [here](https://blog.toshima.ru/2017/04/06/saved-change-to-attribute.html)

Answer (score 16):

`ActiveModel::Dirty` didn't work for me because the `@model.update_attributes()` hid the changes. So this is how I detected changes it in an `update` method in a controller:

```
def update
  @model = Model.find(params[:id])
  detect_changes

  if @model.update_attributes(params[:model])
    do_stuff if attr_changed?
  end
end

private

def detect_changes
  @changed = []
  @changed << :attr if @model.attr != params[:model][:attr]
end

def attr_changed?
  @changed.include :attr
end
```

If you're trying to detect a lot of attribute changes it could get messy though.  Probably shouldn't do this in a controller, but meh.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can do this with `previous_changes` which is also available by default.

Comment: `#update_attributes` doesn't hide the changes. It saves the record, so the model is updated and there are no changes. You need to change the field in the model and check for `changed?` before you save it. ie. @model.field = 'foo' or `@model.attributes = @model.attributes.merge(params[:model])`

Answer (score 2):

Above answers are better but yet for knowledge we have another approch as well,
Lets 'catagory' column value changed for an object (@design),

```
@design.changes.has_key?('catagory')
```

The .changes will return a hash with key as column's name and values as a array with two values [old_value, new_value] for each columns. For example catagory for above is changed from 'ABC' to 'XYZ' of @design,

```
@design.changes   # => {} 
@design.catagory = 'XYZ'
@design.changes # => { 'catagory' => ['ABC', 'XYZ'] }
```

For references [change in ROR](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty/changes)