# Rails strange behavior of production app running on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku

In user model I've got attribute location of type point. Now I've got a validation code:

```
validates :location, :format => { :with => /\(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?,-?\d(?:\.\d+)?\)/,
                                    :on => :update,
                                    :if => :location_changed? }
```

It works fine in console, on localhost, but on heroku it returns:

> Processing by UsersController#update as */* 2012-07-31T18:14:37+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   Parameters:
>   {"user"=>{"location"=>"(3.545452,2.4353534)"}, "id"=>"self"}
>   2012-07-31T18:14:37+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server
>   Error in 13ms 2012-07-31T18:14:37+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2012-07-31T18:14:37+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method
>   `location_changed?' for #<User:0x00000004dc29c8>):
>   2012-07-31T18:14:37+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in`update'

Actually it works also great in heroku console, but don't work in curl request.

Rails version 3.2.7.

```
attr_accessible :profile_picture, :password, :location
```

Thanks!

Comment: it might help showing the code of your model...

Comment: A huge amount of code in a model. Which part do you need?

Comment: the part with the method that is missing?

Comment: Its a standart rails helper, aka attr_changed?. So i haven't got any code, which relates with this part of validation. The main problem, that it works fine on a local machine.

Comment: what do you mean by "standart rails helper" ? something in ```app/helpers```? in this case you will need to ```include``` it into your model in any environment that does no live class-reloading!

Comment: its a part of rails api; standard method like .nil? .blank? etc.

Comment: i've never seen ```location_changed?``` in any rails documentation. could you provide a link to it?

Comment: OK, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051135/rails-3-check-if-attribute-changed

Comment: http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html

Comment: what?!?! i think you are not getting anything! i want to see the code of the method that you are referencing to in your validation and that rails complains about and it's name is ```location_changed?``` this is not part of any rails api. it's a custom method that you are implementing in your model.

Comment: It looks like you're joking! ActiveModel::Dirty - includes in a default rails build, i can use these methods in any model. For example MyModel.changed? ; MyModel.some_attr_changed? etc.. I don't need to implement them by myself. They already exist and goes out of the box=) lol if you don't understand it. Thanks for help.

Comment: sorry, you are right, i did not know of this little magic-helper!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a magic. I fixed it with recreation if table and server restart. Very strange.