# Can you use dirty attributes methods with current_user in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, erb

I am trying to detect whether a user changes there first name or last name.  I was wondering if you can use current_user with dirty attributes?  I was thinking along the lines of

```
 <% if current_user.first_name.changed? == true || current_user.last_name.changed? == true %>
      <h4>Name Changed</h4>
  <% end %>
```

I get this error

undefined method `changed?' for "john":String

Does anyone know of a way of doing this?  might be missing something obvious. Thanks
-John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not `.changed?`,it is `_changed?`

```
 <% if current_user.first_name_changed? == true || current_user.last_name_changed? == true %>
      <h4>Name Changed</h4>
  <% end %>
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051135/rails-3-check-if-attribute-changed)