# Skip specific columns of a model in delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have used delayed_job in a ruby on rails application. As part of that application I have a model Student which is being observed by delayed_job so that a certain action can be taken on update of a Student. But I don't want to call delayed_job on update of certain columns of Student. So basically I want to skip some specific columns of a model in delayed_job.

I have thought of doing that by using some application level flag variables so that delayed_job will only be called when only the flag is reset. But I'll have a problem when multiple instances of the same application process. I mean concurrency issues may arise. So it will not work. I have no idea if there is any way to do that.

Comment: why don't you use it manually for some actions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. Are u suggesting not to use delayed_job?

Comment: No, I'm saying instead of using it on whole model use it manually in controller actions

Comment: If you wants to run delayed for specific columns, use below link to check if that is being updated or not if yes then which column etc.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051135/rails-3-check-if-attribute-changed

Comment: second part of your question don't know much but check if this link help to get this done http://ternarylabs.com/2012/04/16/handle-job-queue-workers-concurrency-in-rails/