# Rails: flash notice unless only certain attributes updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to show a flash notice in my Rails app all the time **unless only** certain attributes are updated.

```
def update
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    if user_params == [:user][:certain_params]
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      redirect_to users_path, notice: "#{@user.name} saved."
    end
  else
    redirect_to edit_user_path(@user), flash: { error: @user.mapped_errors }
  end
end
```

Something like this pseudocode?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "unless only"... are you saying that the user must change certain attributes? He's not allowed to leave them unchanged?

Comment: If only one particular attribute is changed, let's call it `photo`, I want to hide the flash message. Otherwise I want it shown.

Comment: So if they change `photo` plus some other attribute, you want to see the message.  If they don't change `photo` but they change some other attribute, you want to see the message.  If they change `photo` but don't change anything else, you *don't* want to see the message. Is that right?

Comment: That's exactly right, yeah.

Comment: Do you need it exactly updated or are you trying to remind them to upload a photo so you want that shown if the photo is not uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `changed` method to get an array of the attributes that are changed, create a flash message if the attributes are not the "non-notify" attributes.

```
def update
  @user.assign_attributes(user_params)
  changed_fields = @user.changed
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "#{@user.name} saved." if changed_fields != ["photo"]
    redirect_to users_path 
  else
    redirect_to edit_user_path(@user), flash: { error: @user.mapped_errors }
  end
end
```

This will show the `saved` notice if they change `photo` plus other attributes, or if they change other attributes but not `photo`.  The message is suppressed only if *only* `photo` is changed.

Comment: Perfect! Thank-you so much.

Comment: I know this was not part of the question, yet I think worth noting: this is NOT working for NESTED ATTRIBUTED

Comment: So add it to the changed_fields list... `changed_fields = (@user.changed + @user.name_of_nested_associations.map(&:changed)).flatten`

Answer (score 0):

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    # lets say you have these attributes to be checked
    attrs = ["street1", "street2", "city", "state", "zipcode"]
    attributes_changed = (@user.changed & attrs).any?
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:notice] = "#{@user.name} saved."  if attributes_changed
    redirect_to users_path
  else
    redirect_to edit_user_path(@user), flash: { error: @user.mapped_errors }
  end
end
```

For more info see
[Rails 3 check if attribute changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051135/rails-3-check-if-attribute-changed#answer-18753036)
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html