# I need to send a request and accept like instagram follow and accept in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created an web app specified in Michael Hartl rails tutorial. In that the followers are directly follow any person. I need to upgrade it based on request and accept. Any links to solution or steps to the solution preferred.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a model called `Request`, where you'll handle the connection between the users and also gives you control which user is sending the request and who's receiving the request. You can have fields like `accepted_at` and `declined_at`.

For example, the `User A` can send a follow request to `User B`. Based if the `User B` accepted the request, you can send a notification to `User A`, and make a connection between `User A` and `User B`.

In the model you can have something like:

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "sender_id" (or some other name like follower)
  belongs_to :sending, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "sending_id" (or some other name like following)
end
```

In your form, you can have something like this:

```
<%= form_with model: @request, method: :put, local: true do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :accepted_at, value: Time.now, type: "hidden" %>
  <%= form.submit "Accept" %>
<% end %>

<%= form_with model: @request, method: :put, local: true do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :declined_at, value: Time.now, type: "hidden" %>
  <%= form.submit "Decline" %>
<% end %>
```

In the controller, you can have

```
def create
  @request = Request.new(request_params)

  if @request.save
      flash[:notice] = "Follow invitation sent!"
      redirect_to followers_path
  else
     flash[:alert] = "Errors. Couldn't send follow request"
     render view_name
  end
end

def update
  @request = Request.find(params[:id])

  @request.assign_attributes(request_params)

  if @request.accepted_at_changed?
   [here make the connection between users]
   flash[:notice] = "You've accepted the follow request"
  end

  if @request.declined_at_changed?
   [do nothing, just update the declined_at field]
   flash[:notice] = "You've declined the follow request"
  end

  if @request.save
   redirect_to followers_path
  else
   redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Not updated follow request!'
  end
end

private

def request_params
  params.require(:request).permit(:sender_id, :sending_id, :accepted_at, :declined_at)
end
```

I think this will give you a raw idea of how to do it. If you have some questions, I'll be glad to help.

Happy Coding.

Comment: From where @request.accepted_at_changed model comes from

Comment: How can display the list of requested users?

Comment: Where do u learn this

Comment: For @request.accepted_at_changed?, you can read more here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed-3F , also you can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5051147/11883546

Comment: For displaying the pending requests of a user, you can create a model method that will find them. Then you can loop thru them something like ```pending_requests.where(accepted_at: nil, declined_at: nil)```

Comment: Once you provide more information, include more context and code samples in your description, we'll be able to help you more. This is something to start with.